# Regex detect URL without http(s):// and www

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to locate urls without protocols in the text, and then add the protocol before them. This means I don't want urls that begin with `http(s)://` or `http(s)://www.`, only the kind of `example.com`. I'm aware that I might accidentally match with any `text1.text2` if I forgot to add a space after a period, so I came up with some rules to make it more like an actual url:

```
(?<=^|\s)(\w*-?\w+\.[a-z]{2,}\S*)
```

---

- `(?<=^|\s)` The URL should be after the newline or a space.
- `\w*-?\w+`  The domain part, could have a dash (-) or not. Since it's after a newline or space, it removes the protocol.
- `[a-z]{2,}` The extension, should be more than 2 letters
- `\S*` The rest of the URL

It works well to match `example.com` or `example.com/x1/x2` and not `https://example.com`. But I think it's a bit clumsy, and it fails if there is . or , after the url.

How can I achieve the same goal more elegantly? I don't need to match urls like `1.1.1.1`. Are there some loopholes in the above rules that I haven't yet considered?

Comment: Duplicate of this stack overflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Comment: `(?<!\S)` in place of `(?<=^|\s)` (with this simple negation you avoid the alternation). If you want to avoid a dot (that ends a sentence), change the last `\S*` to `\S*(?<![.])`. (But whatever you do, don't dream, it can't be perfect even if your pattern fully and precisely describes the URL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

For elegance, I would put at least one line of comment pointing to this;
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034#section-3.5

You will notice that there is no limit on the top level domain (Belgian, Dutch, and French domains would like to have a word with .be, .nl, and .fr)

It's unclear if your regex deals well with subdomains

Personally, I would break out the regex in to it's components, following the URL I provided.